# Snowflake Snowpark Python: Group By and Concat

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this in Snowflake

| id_request | alert_code |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | R70 |
| 100 | R69 |
| 100 | R54 |
| 101 | R24 |
| 101 | R93 |

I want to turn it into this

| id_request | alert_all |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | R70,R69,R54 |
| 101 | R24,R93 |

I tried writing this but it seems to be wrong

```
df_alerts_3 = df_alerts_2.groupBy('id_request')\
.agg(concat_ws(lit(','), array_agg('alert_code')).alias('alert_all'))
```

Thank you very much for any assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CONCAT_WS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat_ws) concatenates strings in context of a single row. To concatenate strings across multiple rows you need to use aggregate function [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg).

Snowpark equivalent is [snowflake.snowpark.functions.listagg](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.listagg.html):

> Returns the concatenated input values, separated by delimiter string
>
> ```
> df.group_by(df.col1).agg(listagg(df.col2. ",")).within_group(df.col2.asc())
> df.select(listagg(df["col2"], ",", False)
> ```

Comment: Thank you, it works.

`df_alerts_3 = df_alerts_2.group_by(df_alerts_2.id_request).agg(listagg(df_alerts_2.alert_code, ",").alias('alert_all'))`